# excel macro saves blank images on new laptop

Tags: excel, vba

with the great help of people here, years ago, I had a simple macro that was saving a group of text boxes as an image. worked great for years

now I want to retire that windows 7 office 2007 laptop and I bought a windows 10 office 2021 laptop.
it has been a decent battle to manage to get excel to run macros, but it runs them now!

issue I have now, that same excel file with macro that worked great for years, is now saving blank pictures on the new laptop.

here is the macro. any reason why the same excel document on excel 2007 was saving as picture great but on excel 2021 it saves blank picture?

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set shp = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 191"))

Set ch = ws.ChartObjects.Add(shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Width, shp.Height)
shp.Select
ch.Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
Selection.Copy

ch.Chart.Paste
Set tt = ch.Chart

tt.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\KP2.png", filtername:="PNG"

ch.Delete
```

thanks!

I wish I had knowledge to try stuff...

Comment: After `ch.Chart.Paste` can you see the pasted image?

Comment: For debugging, you can use `F9` to set a breakpoint on the line you want it to stop, and then check its progress vs what you expected to happen before it completes.